# can anyone give me example of call method of skscene class from sknode class

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

In MyScene class subclass of `SKScene`

```
- (void)increaseScoreBy:(float)amount
{
    score += amount;
    scoreNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score:%1.0f", score];       
}
```

In employee class subclass of `SKNode`

```
MyScene *objmyscene;
[objmyscene increaseScoreBy:2];
```

I want to call `increaseScoreBy:` method from the employee class (subclass of `SkNode`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  employee class hold pointer for parent as scene. While creating employee object send parent pointer.

```
// use this in employee class
+(id)initWithParent:(id)InParent
{
     employee *obj = [employee alloc] init];
     obj.parentNode = InParent
     return obj;
}
```

//you can access MyScene object  employee class

```
  MyScene *objmyscene = (MyScene*)self.parentNode;
```